# The signature of 'parse' is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, server, deprecated

I am creating a node server, but there is an obsolete function. I have the following error in my code:

```
The signature '(urlString: string): UrlWithStringQuery' of 'parse' is deprecated.ts(6387)
url.d.ts(63, 8): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
(alias) parse(urlString: string): UrlWithStringQuery (+3 overloads)
import parse
The url.parse() method takes a URL string, parses it, and returns a URL object.

A TypeError is thrown if urlString is not a string.
```

My code is:

```
    server.on('request', function (req, res) {
 var filename = parse(req.url).pathname,
     fullPath,
     extension;

 ...
```

What can I use instead of parse(req.url).pathname?

Comment: Why would you be getting TS errors at all, if your code is plain JS? Can you add some more details that explain exactly what you're doing here, ideally as some kind of [mcve] description?

Comment: Pretty sure it wants you to use `new URL(...)` in newer versions. https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost what version of node are you using? Does it match the TypeScript node version types?